Git Extensions: просмотр WEBP как изображения?
Делал коммит который содержал изображения в форматах PNG и WEBP. С удивлением обнаружил, что Git Extensions в окне коммита показывает PNG как изображения, а WEBP как бинарные файлы. Посмотрел в настройках Git Extensions и не смог найти такой настройки, которая бы задавала какие типы файлов каким просмотрщиком показывать.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно изменить настройки Git Extensions , чтобы оно показывало WEBP тоже как изображения?

кроме браузеров почти никакой софт webp отображать не умеет
